# Setting input to required disables the redirection to <form>'s action destination

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm sorry if the title is confusing, here are the details:
I have a simple HTML page with a <form> and a submit button that also redirects to the '/conclusion' page like so:

```
<div class="questions-form"> 
        <form  action="/conclusion" method="get">
        <p><strong> Question ... ?</strong></p>

            <input type="radio" name="qfb_r1" value="1"> First option ...<br>
            <input type="radio" name="qfb_r1" value="2"> Second option ...<br>
            ....

            <p style="margin-top: 100px;">
                <input class="link-btn button" type="submit" value="Next page"/>
            </p>
        </form>
</div>
```

This worked flawlessly until I added this script to make all answers required:

```
const inputs  = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length - 1; i++) {
    inputs[i].required = true;
}
```

---

On the Flask side, not much is happening:

```
@app.route('/conclusion')
def conclusion():
    #collect the answers from the form
    final_answers_b = request.args
    session["final_answers_b"] = final_answers_b.to_dict()
    #save the answers to some DB
    return render_template("conclusion.html")
```

Also note that this code (Flask+HTML+JS) is working just fine on other pages that have pretty much the same content (form on page 1 with mandatory answers and submit button that redirects to page2 when all the questions are answered. In Flask page2 collects the answers of page 1 from the url and continue the processing ...).

- I changed 'get' to 'post' in <form>
- I added methods=['GET', 'POST'] for /conclusion like it's the case on the other routes in Flask
- I tried this:

```
<form onsubmit="redirect()">
</form>

<script>
  function redirect() {
            window.location.assign("conclusion");
            // also window.open({{url_for('conclusion')}}
  }
</script>
```

I want to understand if the problem actually comes from the input.required, because I don't receive any error message that helps me figure out where the problem is. But for now, this happens only when the input.required thing is activated. I mean, when I keep the answers optional, everything works just fine.

Comment: If you inspect HTML in DevTools, do you actually see the attributes `required` in every input? Are there errors in console?

Comment: Yes, the `required` attribute is true for every input. If I click on the submit button before I answer all questions, I actually get the pop-up saying "Please select one of the options", so that's working as expected. And no, I don't have any errors in console. :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I had this "Other" option that, when selected, a text box appears next to it, and of course the text box is also set to `required` by the JS script above. So when the "Other" option is not selected, the box doesn't appear, but the button still needs that `input` to be filled out. So I had to add `text_box.required = false` to the script managing the appearance of the text box when "Other" is selected:

```
<input type="radio" name="qfb_r1" value="7" id="option-other">Other 
      <input type="text" id="option-other-text" placeholder="..." style="display: none;">

<script>
        //Display text box when option Other is selected
        const text_box = document.getElementById('option-other-text');
        function handleRadioClick() {
        if (document.getElementById('option-other').checked) {
            text_box.style.display = 'inline-block';
            text_box.required = true
        } else {
            text_box.style.display = 'none';
            text_box.required = false
        }
        }
        const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="qfb_r1"]');
        radioButtons.forEach(radio => {
        radio.addEventListener('click', handleRadioClick);
        });
    </script>
```